# Short linear basis expansion for support vector regression

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, svm, basis-function

In support vector regression (SVR), I know that many different linear basis expansions for the predictors can be used. I am interested in a basis expansion that is as algebraically short as possible for use in an algebraic modelling optimizer.

To show examples of the non-linearity of the response, I have generated the plots below by sampling different values of only a single predictor at a time (e.g., occDens or THeatDay). These are rather extreme cases of non-linearity; in most of the observations, the response is quite linear. I also want to point out (if relevant) that my predictors are not in the same physical units.

**Questions:**

1. What basis expansions would you recommend for my SVR problem?
2. How could the chosen basis expansions along with the fitted coefficients be used to make an algebraic prediction?

[image]
[image]